# Lotus notes 8.5 quota

Tags: lotus-notes, ibm-domino

we're using lotus notes 8.5 and I have a user who was over his quota as he had sent 6 email with attachement over 800 MB (no comment...)
I deleted these oversized email and empty the trash but domino keep sending email warning about quota. I checked in the all documents view and they are no longer there, I re-did an empty the trash. I saw a post on the internet saying to compact his database, when I go under file, application, properties and click on the info tab, I see that he use 35.7% of the 3 GB database. when I click on "compact" I see a message saying the compact of the database is beeing process... the message disapear after about 1 minutes the message disapear but nothing else seem to happen and when I look back later on the space problem has not changed.

any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered powering off the server and blaming the dumbass who tried to cram a DVD through your mail server in 6 emails?  In all seriousness, I'd probably use the opportunity to take the server offline and do whatever maintenance is needed.  If anyone asks, that user crashed it by abusing his network access/email account.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Problem is that the dumbass is part of the management team :)

Comment: All the more reason!  If you don't blame the management team, who will? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are compacting the database on the server and not the local replica.

Comment: I sent the command on the server, how will I know it's completed ?

Comment: You'll get a console message that it's completed and freed up x amount of space.  It can take a while.  Alternately, you can try opening up the mail file to  see if it's still locked by the compact process or not.

Comment: Oh, can't edit comment now...

As I recall, the message looks like "Compacted mail\userid.nsf, freed xK bytes (x%)" and is followed by a line saying "database compactor process shutdown" or something like that.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Thanks alot, this seem to have resolved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

With Lotus Domino, the compact runs in the background on the Domino server and can take some time on a large mail file.

Once the compact has completed, you may need to re-open the mail file to notice the effects.

Comment: I did send the command straight on the server to compact the database. How do I know the compact is completed and how do I re-open the mail file ? I'm pretty new to domino administration.

Comment: HopelessN00b has already answered the part about knowing when it's completed. As for re-opening the mail file, that's just within the Notes client. Quit Notes and open it again :-)